# How to install msi one after another .net?

Tags: .net, installation, installshield

I've made an vb.net application that requires crystal reports 10 and I need to redistribute my application.

So...

I need to install *XP SP3* THEN -> *.net framework 4* THEN -> *crystal reports redistuble package and my application*  and that packages are installed in series one after another (*means that you have to wait for the first package to finish its installation and then run the next installation package*) not simultaneously at one time.

Some users are not professional at computer and get nervous about installing those files in series SO I want a small application or an installer that takes over that operation and runs the files one after another any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a great free installer script called [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It has many examples on how to install [.NET Framwork](http://priyank.co.in/install-dot-net-framework-using-inno-setup) and [Crystal Reports](http://www.sportamok.com/development/delphi/15-crystal-report-9-inno-setup). The installer will allow you to chain multiple packages together and create a simple installer UI for your users. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup) is a great pre-made script that will check and install the .NET Framework. There are many more examples on google.

Answer (score 1):

You need a bootstrapper. You can make one using a tool like [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) (with the Burn bootstrapper introduced in 3.6).

Answer (score 1):

I have used [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) on several occasions with success. Try it first. It is available on codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two important points:

1) You are taking a huge risk assuming you can install an entire Windows Service pack without error.

2) [XP SP3 is *NOT* redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24).

> The Microsoft Download Center site is your only authorized web source
>   for downloading a licensed copy of Windows XP Service Pack 3. To
>   report a website offering unlicensed copies of Windows XP SP3 for
>   download, please send e-mail to: piracy@microsoft.com or visit
>   http://www.microsoft.com/piracy/ReportingUs.mspx.

Tell your users to turn on Windows Update and they will get XP SP3 and .NET 4.0 automatically.  All your installer should do is check that those requirements are met and abort if they are not there. (AppSearch and LaunchConditions tables)